# How do I turn off Stories to Read in Google Now?

Tags: google-now

I do not want to see the Stories To Read cards in Google now. Is there any way to turn this feature off? I can only see an option to turn it off for particular websites.

Answer (score 8):

Since [Google's redesigned Feed as a replacement of Google Now on July 19, 2017](https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/252721-google-announced-redesigned-feed-replacement-google-now), there's no easy way to remove *Stories to read* but to block every single source/topic.

[James Wald commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/how-do-i-turn-off-stories-to-read-in-google-now/140294?noredirect=1#comment236821_140294):

> I was able to defeat the "Stories to read" section by blocking every single source using "Not interested in stories from ..." on each card. The stories section is now gone from my Google Now feed. There are hundreds of sources, so it took a while.

However [they also mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/how-do-i-turn-off-stories-to-read-in-google-now/140294?noredirect=1#comment237170_140294),

> The only addition worth mentioning is that Google matches additional story sources over time, so the Stories section tends to reappear, requiring more manual blocking. It may not be such a great solution after all.

(Note: not tested personally)

Comment: I already had, "Interested in getting recommendations from around the web" turned off. I also don't see "Never show stories to read" in my version of Google Now (shows no updates available either)

Comment: I was able to defeat the "Stories to read" section by blocking every single source using "Not interested in stories from ..." on each card. The stories section is now gone from my Google Now feed. There are hundreds of sources, so it took a while.

Comment: @JamesWald Could you add that as a new answer? Good suggestions should be visible as answers, not buried in the comments of an old answer that's no longer valid.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points on this network to post an answer to a protected question, but feel free to copy my comment and post a new answer if you're able to. The only addition worth mentioning is that Google matches additional story sources over time, so the Stories section tends to reappear, requiring more manual blocking. It may not be such a great solution after all.

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though you can't turn off stories to read without turning on Web & App Activity, which saves (and presumably allows google to see) all of your searches and browsing history.

So you can either (a) not use Google Now (b) be annoyed with trashy clickbait "stories" (c) allow Google to see, save, and track all of your searches and browsing history or (d) start a class-action lawsuit.

Answer (score 2):

See google reply here.
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2824784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Steps
1. Open Google app.
2. Goto "Settings"
3. Select "Your feed"
4. Either turn off notifications by diaabling "Feed" option or first "Delete Card preferences" and then disabling "Feed" toggle.

Comment: This turns off the whole feed, not just the stories to read section

Answer (score -3):

Long press on Desktop, press "Settings", press "Your feed", Turn on the feed "Yes/No".

[image]